# Working with 2D building footprints and ArcGIS Pro / CityEngine

Tags: 3d, footprint, cityengine, 2d

I've been trying for a few days now to create 3D buildings from my 2D building footprints. All the tutorials I've been through let me down right where it counts so I've decided to ask the pro's here.

My 2D footprints do have height attributes and I know there is a way to extrude them. However I cannot make this happen with a single building nor the entire group. Can someone explain in fine detail how I should get this done?

The image below is after selecting one building. You can see that height exists, however extruding rules are not explained very well [here](http://cehelp.esri.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.procedural.cityengine.help/html/manual/cga/shape_operations/cga_so_extrusion.html).
[image]

Comment: As it stands I think your question is too broad because you are asking potential answerers to provide you with the steps instead of describing in detail what you have done to let them know the step where what you observe first departs from what you would expect.  Also, your question does not mention ArcGIS Pro but you had a tag for it that I am removing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that this was as easy as I expected but had to get help from a pro in order to write the proper rule file.

So since my shapefile had height data in the form of an attribute `BLDG_HGT` I was able to extrude the 2D building footprints dynamically by applying this rule file:

```
/**
 * File:    extrude-rules.cga
 * Created: 4 Apr 2016 19:28:19 GMT
 * Author:  bracicot
 */

version "2015.2"

attr BLDG_HGT =0

@startRule
Lot -->
extrude(world.y, BLDG_HGT)
```